# How to have an array of volatile booleans in Java and not a volatile array of booleans?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, cas, locks

So I want an array with 10 volatile booleans, not a volatile array with 10 booleans. It probably does not even make sense to have a volatile array reference, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: And why would you want an array of volatile booleans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the only way is to have a AtomicBoolean[] or an AtomicIntegerArray. Then they do not need to be volatile. Its elements will be.

If you want more fun, check this question: [Which is "better". AtomicIntegerArray (1/0 as true/false) versus AtomicBoolean[]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22236928/which-is-better-atomicintegerarray-1-0-as-true-false-versus-atomicboolean)

Answer (score 1):

If it's only 10 and is always 10, you could simply write:

```
private volatile boolean b1, b2, ..., b10;
```

A possibly cleaner way would be to use [an `AtomicIntegerArray(10)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicIntegerArray.html) and map between integers and booleans (0=false, 1=true).

You should clarify the reason why you need 10 volatile booleans: there may be a better way.

Comment: 10 was just an example. I would be needing N. But if we give it a thought we conclude that this is worthless. I can just use AtomicBoolean[], right?

Comment: Yes you could have a `private volatile AtomicBoolean[]` so both the array and its components are volatile.

Comment: @John Since you probably don't want to ever replace the array itself, better make it `final` and non-volatile. As long as you initialize it in the constructor that's thread-safe too.